# Pulling from remote repository without changing the updated local files

Tags: github

We are working as a group and all push their changes to GitHub master branch. Currently, the remote repo is updated but at the same time, I created another notebook in my local repo.

Which command should I use to pull the changes of others without losing my new notebook?

Answer (score 0):

When doing a `git pull` if conflicts exist these will need to be merged your changes will not be lost as such. Other options include performing `git stash` to park current work to one side without the need to perform a commit yet. (stashed stuff can be later applied)

I would also recommend working in a local branch if you are expecting conflicting changes and dealing with this when you refresh your branch.